# How do you add multiple videos on a page?

Tags: html, video

What I am trying to do is setup a ton of videos playing at once on a single page. The entire page would be covered with videos. There is no white-space. Kinda like a collage of footage playing all over a grid. Imagine the page divided up in 12 squares and each one has a video.

It would look like 12 monitors right next to one another, playing different footage with sound.

Comment: Do show us what code you have used to achieve this and what the result was. And of course what you needed it to be.

Comment: have 12 `<video>` elements on the page. you'll need to optimize the videos so you don't swamp either bandwidth to the computer, or playback capabilities